# Castle windsor typed factory - resolving generic service using runtime type as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

I have a typed factory with this method:

```
IRepository<T> Get<T>() where T : class
```

and the following component type selector:

```
public class RepositoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
    {
        protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
        {
            return ComponentNames.Repository;
        }

        protected override Type GetComponentType(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
        {
               return typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(method.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
        }
    }
```

What I would like however, is to have a factory implementation that returns a Repository, but by only having to specify a parameter of type Type, not a compile time type parameter.

Example (not valid code) - I want the T to be the Type provided

```
IRepository<T> Get(Type type);
```

I am aware that this does not compile because the method itself has to be generic, but I don't know the parameter beforehand.

What I am trying to achieve is to simplify this pattern:

```
if (documentType == SomeEnum.x)
{
    this.RepositoryFactory.Get<X>().Update(document as X);
}
else if (documentType == SomeEnum.y)
{
    this.RepositoryFactory.Get<Y>().Update(document as Y);
}
else if (documentType == SomeEnum.z)
{
    this.RepositoryFactory.Get<Z>().Update(document as Z);
}
```

by resolving the factory based on the enum (or an extension to that enum returning Type).

Is there a way to achieve this with Castle Windsor, or any other approaches I could take?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is more about polymorphism and general dispatching problem, rather than hooking this into container.

You can use double dispatch approach:

```
public void Save(DocumentBase document)
{
    var dispatcher = new DocumentDispatcher();
    document.Accept(dispatcher);
}

public abstract class DocumentBase
{
    public abstract void Accept(IDocumentDispatcher dispatcher);
}

public class DocumentA : DocumentBase
{
    public override void Accept(IDocumentDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher.Dispatch(this);
    }
}

public class DocumentB : DocumentBase
{
    public override void Accept(IDocumentDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher.Dispatch(this);
    }
}

public interface IDocumentDispatcher
{
    void Dispatch(DocumentA document);

    void Dispatch(DocumentB document);
}

public class DocumentDispatcher : IDocumentDispatcher
{
    public void Dispatch(DocumentA document)
    {
        this.RepositoryFactory.Get<DocumentA>().Update(document);
    }

    public void Dispatch(DocumentB document)
    {
        this.RepositoryFactory.Get<DocumentB>().Update(document);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use dynamic dispatch:

```
public void Save(DocumentBase document)
{
    var dispatcher = new DocumentDispatcher();
    dispatcher.Dispatch((dynamic)document);
}

public class DocumentDispatcher : IDocumentDispatcher
{
    public void Dispatch<T>(T document)
    {
        this.RepositoryFactory.Get<T>().Update(document);
    }
}
```

Or even dictionary dispatch:

```
public void Save(DocumentBase document)
{
    var actions = new Dictionary<Type, Action<DocumentBase>>
                      {
                          { typeof(DocumentA), d => this.RepositoryFactory.Get<DocumentA>().Update((DocumentA)d) },
                          { typeof(DocumentB), d => this.RepositoryFactory.Get<DocumentB>().Update((DocumentB)d) },
                      };

    actions[typeof(DocumentBase)](document);
}
```

I prefer first solution as it is only one type safe solution.

Comment: I don't think the double dispatch approach is usable in this case. I don't have an inheritance hierarchy, just an enum based on which i decide. I also don't like all the extra boilerplate code. The dictionary dispatch could work, but only for Action<> methods. If it is a Func<T>, i am in the same place I was in - i would have to have the method return object and then cast it, right?

Comment: Followup comment: I misunderstood the double dispatch approach. It would work for me. However, I still don't like all the extra boilerplate. Additionally, it seems to me that this way I am making my POCO objects take on dependencies (only through a parameter, but still).

Comment: @FreHu, If the first solution works, than second will work as well...less coding, no need to add any methods on your POCO objects, but less type safety. If you don't like extra coding, you will have problems anyway. IMHO creating some Castle boiler plate code like your `RepositoryComponentSelector ` is even worse boiler plating. And about your POCO problem, class would be dependent only on your interface, nothing concrete. There is no practical reason why this should be a problem.